# using sapply with a function that has multiple arguments

Tags: r, bradleyterry2

I have a list of multiple data frames (called prep1). Each data frame has the following format(only the first 6 rows shown)

```
 player1        player2  win1 win2
  1 a12TTT.pdf  a21.pdf    0    1
  2 a12TTT.pdf  B11.pdf    1    0
  3 a12TTT.pdf  B12.pdf    1    1
  4 a12TTT.pdf  B24.pdf    0    2
  5 a12TTT.pdf  B4.pdf     0    1
  6 a12TTT.pdf  B8.pdf     0    1
```

I want to model the data using function BTm from BradleyTerry2 package .
With a single data frame the function is

```
BTm(cbind(win1,win2), player1, player2, data= your.data.frame.name)
```

I try to do the same but on all dataframes from the list at once using sapply and passing all the arguments from BTm instead of ..... in the sapply arguments (the documentation says: ... optional arguments to FUN).

```
sapply (prep1, BTm, cbind(win1, win2), player1, player2, data = prep1)
```

It gets me the following error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'player2' not found`
I get the same error if I use `lapply`.

I do not know how to pass all the arguments correctly. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an anonymous function for clarity -

```
sapply(prep1, function(x) BTm(cbind(win1,win2), player1, player2, data= x))
```

The same should work with `lapply` as well.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(prep1, ~ BTm(cbind(win1, win2), player1, player, data = .x))
```